# Error 522 on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, cloudflare

I am posting this from the mobile app.  On my desktop browser I am getting an Error 522 when trying to access multiple SE sites:

[image: screen shot of CloudFlare error page]

EDIT: Just after I posted this, I am no longer seeing the Error 522.

Comment: Corollary post on mSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323474/1849664

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange was having some kind of issue with CloudFlare, so [they bypassed CloudFlare](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/733677968862674946), which is why the Stack Exchange sites are up now.

[image: @StackStatus]
[image: @Nick_Craver]

Despite the error (in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJIcm.jpg)) showing that CloudFlare is up and Stack Exchange is down, Stack Exchange found that [their side is up and running](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/733678800257552384), which is why bypassing CloudFlare brought the network back up.

[image: @Nick_Craver]

---

### Technical Details

The actual bypass that Stack Exchange applied was changing the nameservers from:

- cf-dns01.stackexchange.com. (173.245.58.53)
- cf-dns02.stackexchange.com. (173.245.59.4)

… to:

- ns1.serverfault.com. (198.252.206.80)
- ns2.serverfault.com. (198.252.206.81)
- ns3.serverfault.com. (192.111.0.80)
- ns4.serverfault.com. (192.111.0.81)

… so that Stack Exchange sites would resolve to their own IP addresses.

They may have also configured CloudFlare to pass traffic through directly, for visitors who had cached DNS records.

The sites were quickly put back on CloudFlare once they confirmed that CloudFlare was able to supply traffic normally.

---

### Resolution

Stack Exchange reported that the issue was caused by a routing problem.  This could mean that the Stack Exchange network wasn't able to send to or receive from CloudFlare.

[image: @StackStatus]

Comment: Meta sites are still being affected by this for me... pretty consistently. It's all in text, no styles are being served up.

Comment: Your DNS is caching the sstatic.com domain @Catija

Comment: @Sklivvz If you say so (you write words but I don't know what they mean)... whatever it was it just fixed itself, so it's cool.

Comment: We use two different sites, one for text, one for the rest. The fix was to tell all browsers to go fetch both sites somewhere else, not where it was faulty. In your case, your browser only got notified of one change, not both.

Comment: Not the first time, or second, or third that CloudFlare is doing this. I honestly have no idea why SE keeps using such a broken thing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It might not have been CloudFlare's fault.  It's conceivable that Stack Exchange accidentally blocked CloudFlare.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Because when it does work, it's hugely beneficial. Having said that, we are looking at other options.

Comment: @Adam well, guess I'm missing details to really know. Still, from the side it doesn't look good. Good luck with the other options!